# C# AggressiveInlining behaviour

Tags: c#, assembly, compiler-optimization, inline-assembly, jit

I know what Inlining is supposed to mean from the JitAsm perspective. What I'm trying to determine is the following scenario
The following assumptions **SHOULD BE CONSIDERED**:

1. This code is a **hotpath** (it essentially gets called every 1 - 100ms)
2. Performance is all that matters (Readability doesn't matter)
3. The use of this attribute should not break any logic inside the method/s (if otherwise I would consider removing it)

```cs
public class A 
{
    B b; //injected here
    
    public async Task FunctionOfMainInterest()
    {
        await b.ShouldBeInlined().ConfigureAwait(false); //Will this get inlined ?
    }
}

public class B
{
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public async Task ShouldBeInlined() 
    {
        //Do something here...
    }
}
```

And pretending it does get inlined could that affect performance after jit finished ***all tiers*** (which I think are enabled by default) ? What exactly are the implications of using it ?

And last question would be pretending there are various other function calls in `class B` that reference just like this example is it worth inlining them as well  (because it seems to me that if this is true then Inlining will **spread** just like `async` does) ?

**UPDATE:**
As stated in the comments I did a sharplab test and compared the results (with and without the attribute). *[Left is without and Right is with]*

[JitAsm Differences](https://www.diffchecker.com/c0diViQn)

Comment: You can probably check how it actually JITs with an asm-level debugger, or whatever tooling https://sharplab.io/ uses to see final fully-optimized JIT asm.  (Look for `call` instructions to find things that aren't inlined.)

Comment: It did something, however it seems to me it added a couple of new instructions (which seems about right thing to do), but I can't really figure out if it is boilerplate or quick jmps. I will edit my post with the image

Comment: It seems like there is one more `call` instruction as well as a `jmp` so I suppose there is something that gets inlined eventually.

Comment: Code called only 10 times per second doesn't seem like a hot path at all; just the opposite.  100 ms is practically forever in CPU time.  Are you sure this is the right place to be focusing your optimization efforts?

Comment: It's actually irregular (a range between 1 - 100), but what essentially matters is performance

Comment: @Damian The link "JitAsm Differences" is expired, could you put the differences (if any) directly here?

Comment: I just used Sharplab.io